# Typerror is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I´ve this error on my code

Typerror: ProjectRepository is not a constructor
    at main.....

This is the code from main.js

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const AppDAO = require('./dao')
const ProjectRepository = require('./project_repository')
const TaskRepository = require('./task_repository')

function main() {

const dao = new AppDAO('./database.sqlite3')
const blogProjectData = {name: 'Write Node.js - SQLite Tutorial'}
const projectRepo = new ProjectRepository(dao)
const taskRepo = new TaskRepository(dao)
let projectId
```

This is project_repository.js class with the constructor

```
class ProjectRepository{
    constructor(dao){
        this.dao = dao
    }
```

It's very simple but I´ve no idea why it´s failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)ing the `ProjectRepository` class.

add `export` before class keyword.

```
export class ProjectRepository{ ... }
```

Maybe it's just a silly mistake, but if you want to learn more about Javascript import and exports you can at [this](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac) link